# Spring boot not rendering jsp view

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring boot with jsp redering as a view for one of the controller. We have interceptor added as well. I have added below details in pom.xml -

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
          <version>9.0.37</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have also added below configuration in application.properties file -

```
       spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
       spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

And my jsp in added inside src/main/resources/webapp/WEB-INF/view/ . From the interceptor I am seeing view is being returned but after that it is not rending to jsp. Interceptor again calling to /error view.
Any help here.  I followed all the blogs but did not worked.

Comment: can you paste your controller?

Comment: ```@Controller
public class HelloController extends AbstractController {


 @RequestMapping(value="/hi", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView handler (Model model) {
    // model.addAttribute("msg", "a jar packaging example");
     return new ModelAndView("hello");
 }

} ```

Comment: This is my controller. Request is coming to controller but while response it is going to ErrorBaseController (/error) which is a default spring view mapping

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the below dependency. Adding this would resolved your issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please show your project structure, the webapp folder must be inside main not under resources

Comment: Sorry type... I have put jsp file into src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/  and also I tried putting under src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/view/ but that also did not work. I am using spring boot version -2.3.3.RELEASE and tomcat-embed-jasper version  - 9.0.37.